# Advanced text editor on react?

Tags: react-native, npm, text-editor

Somebody know a NPM that allows me to edit texts using style like bold, italic, add image , etc... Something like a microsoft word. There's something like this on RN? Edit: I want a text editor.

Comment: check [React Rich Text Editor](https://github.com/sstur/react-rte)

Answer (score 0):

Try Quill text editor https://www.npmjs.com/package/quill

```
> npm install quill
```